# how to hide id in url in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am creating ecommerce website in Laravel and I want to hide productdetails id in url. What can I change in code plz need solution.

Web.php

```
Route::get('/productdetail{id}','ProductDetailController@display_products_details');
```

controller code:

```
 public function display_products_details($id)
    {
        $data = DB::select('select * from subcategory inner join product_details on subcategory.sub_id=product_details.sub_id where product_details.sub_id = ?',[$id]);
        return view('productdetails',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

link tag code:

```
<a href="/productdetail{{ $value->sub_id }}">{{ $value->name_of_subcategory }}</a>
```

path I getting:
localhost:8000/productdetail12

But actually I want Localhost:8000/productdetail

Comment: how would you know what product you were referring to without an identifier?

Comment: you can not do that. For it to work, the id needs to be visible. You should also add a " / " before the {id}.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having the id as part of the request body so it will not be visible in the URL (it will still be visible to anyone inspecting the request body via  their browser developer tools).

You can do this by using a form to send a post request:

```
Route::post('/productdetail','ProductDetailController@display_products_details');
```

The link will change to a form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('ProductDetailController@display_products_details') }}>
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{  $value->sub_id  }}" />
<button type="submit">{{ $value->name_of_subcategory }}</button>
</form>
```

You may need to style the button to look like a link.

The controller becomes:

```
public function display_products_details(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([ 'id' => 'required|int' ]);
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $data = DB::select('select * from subcategory inner join product_details on subcategory.sub_id=product_details.sub_id where product_details.sub_id = ?',[$id]);
        return view('productdetails',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

Note that while this is theoretically possible it does result in very bad user experience. People can't share product links with others for example

Comment: hello, actually i am clicking on image the i am getting product details , how can i use button for linking..

Comment: I can't see an image in your question, and it shouldn't really matter. The button contents can be an image or just text. It's just going to come down to styling